# Why do webkit-1.0 and gtk+-3.0 have more than 900 same symbols in .vapi files

Tags: vala, vapi

As the title says my problem is that I try to use both gtk 3 and webkit 1.

I am following this example https://live.gnome.org/Vala/WebKitSample

except that I am using gtk 3 instead of 2.

I am using valac 0.16.0

I have now noticed that errors are Gdk 2 and Gdk 3 same symbols.

This seems like a way to solve my problems [link](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2011-July/msg00006.html)
but it is nonstandard.

Nevermind, I have fixed it with a bundled webkitgtk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use library webkit-1.0 with gtk+-3.0, because webkit-1.0 depends on gtk+-2.0 and gdk-2.0 that conflict with gtk+-3.0 and gdk-3.0. You have to use library webkitgtk-3.0 that has same API as webkit-1.0, but depends on gtk+-3.0 and gdk-3.0.

Since webkigtk-3.0 bindings are not shipped with Vala ([bug 676249](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676249)), you have to create your own bindings (follow instructions in [the mentioned e-mail](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2011-July/msg00006.html)) and tell valac where your webkigtk-3.0.vapi file is located (`--vapidir=.`).

```
$ ls
webkitgtk-3.0.deps  webkitgtk-3.0.vapi  webkit-sample.vala
$ valac --vapidir=. --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg webkitgtk-3.0 --thread webkit-sample.vala
/tmp/fenryxo/webkit-sample.vala.c: In function ‘vala_browser_create_widgets’:
/tmp/fenryxo/webkit-sample.vala.c:206:2: warning: ‘gtk_vbox_new’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkvbox.h:60): Use 'gtk_box_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
$ ls
webkitgtk-3.0.deps  webkitgtk-3.0.vapi  webkit-sample  webkit-sample.vala
```

Comment: This is great, but i cant get the webkit frame to load the web page.